# Sql Anywhere : Find difference between two tables with same columns

Tags: union, diff, union-all, except, sqlanywhere

I have two tables with large number of columns, but same columns in both tables. Is there an easy way to find difference between two tables in Sql Anywhere (without joins if possible, as number of columns are too many)? EXCEPT and INTERSECT are not supported in Sql Anywhere. I ultimately need to verify if the two tables are identical, and to get the rows which are different

I tried counting rows using union all and union. Both tables have same number of rows, 12352 and union all returns twice of this number, 24704. But union is resulting in 12357 rows, which has got me confused